# OpenTracing/corellation-id in email header

Tags: email-headers, opentracing

I wonder if a good idea to add some of tracing values from Open Tracing specification into emails headers, like it injected into HTTP headers. It will help us to understand what service had send specific email message in customer cases.

Is this a valid case for open tracing?

What MIME headers I should use for this?